# ip_local_port_range kernel parameter confusion

Tags: linux, kernel, voip

On my system we have following setting:

```
[root@voip ~]# cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
32768   61000
```

We have asterisk running on it which is using RTP port range `12000-13000` in case we want to increase RTP range from `12000-40000` then how it will impact on `ip_local_port_range` setting?

How it works and where?

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk will use ports outside the ip_local_port_range, so you don't want them to overlap.